# Unhandled Exception on button click event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, datatemplate

I've bound a datatable (which is populated at run-time) to my datagrid and have one column which lists file paths. I'm customizing that column to replace the file path with an image button to open the file when clicked. I'm getting the following error, but haven't been able to resolve. Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

*Error:
An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll
Additional information: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a definition for 'Master'*

**I'm getting the error on my button event... "d.Master".**

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button2 = (Button)e.OriginalSource;
    dynamic d = button2.DataContext;
    string filepath = d.Master;
    Process.Start(filepath); 
}
```

**DataGrid:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          Margin="650,197,449,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="True" AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AugoGeneratingColumn" ItemsSource="{Binding fileTable}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Master" CellTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate2}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**DataTemplate**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate2">
<Button Name="fileButton" Click="ButtonClick" Width="30" Height="30" BorderBrush="#FF707070" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Images\PDFicon.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

**AutoGeneratingColumn method:**

```
private void DataGrid_AugoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.Header.ToString() == "Master")
    {
        DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn    //create new template column
        CellTemplate = (DataTemplate) Resources["DataTemplate2"]
        e.Column = templateColumn; // Replace the auto-generated column with the templateColumn.
    }
    else
    {
        e.Column.Header = "Expired";
    }
}
```

Comment: The error seems clear enough. Your code assumes the object has a `Master` property, but it doesn't. But you haven't provided a good [mcve] that shows clearly the context of this code and what you might have meant instead of trying to get a `Master` property. Maybe you can add a `Master` property as suggested, maybe not. Impossible to know without a better code example.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to get an undefined `Master` from button's `DataContext`? ie why the error is coming.

Since `fileTable` is the source of your data grid, you need to have an item `Master` in the `fileTable` data type. Since it is not defined yet, the error will be produced.

The best solution is to have a `Master` property in the data class of your ItemsSource, and fill the property accordingly, so that during button click, you can access it via the DataContext like how you are doing now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, that pointed me in the right direction. I thought the DataContext was pointing me toward the datatable's "Master" column itself, which is generated at runtime and not a true property. I fixed my problem by identifying the selected cell, instead.

```
        private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get column Index of selected cell & set as variable
        int colIndex = BoundPivotGrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
       DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)BoundPivotGrid.SelectedItem;
        String valueOfItem = drv[colIndex].ToString();

        if (valueOfItem == "-")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No file");
        }
        else
        {
            Process.Start(valueOfItem);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is "string filepath = d.Master;". d is of type DataRowView, which doesn't have a property called Master. Change dynamic to var and it will fail at compile time instead of runtime

Comment: This doesn't seem like an answer to me. Changing an exception into a compile-time error doesn't solve the problem. It just moves it. (The advice is also not that helpful anyway; `DataContext` has the type `object`, so sure `var` will fail at compile time, but not in a way that tells you anything. It would fail even if `dynamic` _didn't_.)

Comment: The answer is the second sentence. d is of type DataRowView, which doesn't have a property called Master

Comment: All that does is reiterate the error message. It says as much. How does that solve the question author's _problem_?